# Let Java wait till previous Try is completed

Tags: java, connection, wait, etl

I have a method that extracts and cleans data from a MySQL database.

Next step in the process is moving this data to Oracle database.

However, during the process of extracting and cleaning the data from MySQL, I have a coninous connection to the oracle db. This is not nescessary and extremely slows down the extraction process.

How do I let java wait till the extracion/cleaning processes are complete and THEN make a connection to Oracle?

This is my code:

```
public void ConvertFiles() {

    try {

        connectToDB();

        RawFile tempFile = new RawFile(super.mFileType);
        try {
            ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

            try {
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM coffeedata");
                int ii = 0;
                while (result.next()) {
                    ii++;
                    System.out.print("Reading Row:" + ii + "/" + 41429 + "\n");
                    mStore = (result.getString(1));
                    mCategory = (result.getString(2));
                    mName = (result.getString(3));

                    // Add columns 2007 Q1 - Q4 t/m 2009 Q1 - Q2 to ArrayList   


                    for (int i = 4; i < 14; i++) {
                        values.add("" + result.getInt(i));

                    }
                    tempFile.addData(new SQLData(mCategory, mName, values, mStore));

                    try {
                        OracleController.DataToOracle();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

                    }
                }

                tempFile.CleanCategory();
                mRawFiles.add(tempFile);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                closeDBConnection();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            //return values;
            //System.out.println(values);


        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

For clarification: I want to let this Try wait till the previous one is completed:

```
try {
    OracleController.DataToOracle();

}
```

Comment: you need a connection to "extract and clean" data from a database

Comment: Yes, but the problem is I am maintaining the connection to the Oracle db when it's not nescessary. I only need that connection after extracion/cleaning process is completed

Comment: Frankly, it's hard to make a parallel between the code and the explanation. But I don't see at all how having an open connection to Oracle would have any impact on the speed of the extraction process. I think you're making incorrect assumptions.

Comment: When I comment out the OracleController.DataToOracle(); then the extraction process goes extremely fast. Now it's like Reading Row:1 ...... Reading Row:2 when commenting out that line it goes like Reading Row:1 ... Reading Row:1000 in less than a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor your code and place your `try` block after `try - catch - finally`that you want to wait.

```
try{
    //block that you need to excecute before
} catch { ... }
// Than your block
try {
     OracleController.DataToOracle();
 } catch (Exception e)


                    }
```

Comment: The try is never reached. No executable location available